# RegExp in Javascript to find all parenthesis constructions

Tags: javascript, regex, math

Well, I have expressions like this: `27+3/(12-5)+9-(2*(12-10)+(7-6))`

I need all the parenthesis to get like this array:

```
[(12-5),(2*(12-10)+(7-6)),(12-10),(7-6)]
```

Or some this array shaped. Is there some easy way to make RegExp for the case? Well, to make smth like:

```
const myExprStr = '27+3/(12-5)+9-(2*(12-10)+(7-6))';
const neededParenthesisArray = [...[], ...myExprStr.matchAll([some magic regexp])];
```

Well, finally. The question is: can someone to share with me the needed RegExp, or, maybe, there is some docs to find oyt how to make the RegExp?

Comment: Do you want to have also the nested parenthesis? If yes, it is not an easy task to do with regex. Is there some maximal level of depth in the parethesis?

Comment: because the standart javascript library does not suppport recursive regex (which by the way you should not use anyway)

Comment: For not nested you could use this: \([^()\n]*\)

Comment: better use some parsers

Comment: @Predicate well, I don't think there is real level. Maybe parenthesis in parenthesis, and once more. Something like this: ```15+(3/(2+(0.5*2)))```. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, actuallythats enough to blow your regex up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you said there would be not much of nesting. You can see how things easily blow up. The reason is the theoretical boundaries of regex, it is a type of language that is more easily to parse, but on the other hand is is not meant to count. By matching nested parenthesis you need to count. If you have only three levels, we can use a trick, but if you want to go deeper, better use an appropriate parser.

capturing all sigle parenthesis:

```
\(([^()\n]*)\)
```

double:

```
\(([^()\n]*\([^()\n]*\)[^()\n]*)+\)
```

tripple:

```
\(([^()\n]*\(([^()\n]*\([^()\n]*\)[^()\n]*)+\))+[^()\n]*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/n8SVYH/1

https://regex101.com/r/n8SVYH/2

https://regex101.com/r/n8SVYH/3